# Read updated registration id using GCM

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM API and gcm.jar given in android documentation. Its working good. But as ***GCM refreshes registration id***  how and where can I listen updated `registration id`?

There is a method `onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId)` in class `GCMIntentService` is this the method which can listen `registration id` (either that id was refreshed by GCM)? Or is there any other way to listen updated registration id? and another confusion Is there any test case where I can test with updated registration id?

My current implementation of `onRegistered()` is

```
@Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);

        dataStore = new DataPrefStore(context);
        //Store registration Id
        dataStore.setRegistrationId(registrationId);
        //Notify GCM registration
        displayMessage(context, Constants.GCM_REGISTER_MESSAGE);

    }
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you please suggest me how can get updated registration id in case, google refreshes registration id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You have right implementation. Whenever the registration id is refreshed it will call your GCMINtentService class onRegistered() method.

```
Note that Google may periodically refresh the registration ID, so you should design your    
Android application with the understanding that the com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION intent may be called multiple times.
```

Comment: Is this mean that onRegistered() will handle updated reg id also? And how can I test if my logic is working or not (if GCM refreshed reg id)?

Comment: Can you test it by doing new registration? and then unregister and then re-register and see if it works. If it works, then it will work even when google refreshes registration id.